# Static route between vlans

Tags: vlan, route

Windows server 2003.
MS TMG with two NICs.

I have two vlans in my network.
vlan1: 200.1.1.0/255.255.255.0
vlan2: 200.1.2.0/255.255.255.0

I have an ISA server with two NICs in vlan2.
NIC1: 200.1.2.100 (default gateway set to nothing - if I set this to 200.1.2.1 then I can ping to vlan1 machines but cant proxy for internet i.e. more than 1 default gateway issue)
NIC2: 125.1.1.125 (default gateway set to 125.1.1.1)
Router IP: 125.1.1.1

I am unable to ping to any IP in vlan1 from this server(200.1.2.100) or from vlan1 to this server(200.1.2.100). I get a "Destination host unreachable" message.

Perhaps I am able to ping from vlan1 to vlan2 (or vice versa) with other machines that have one NIC installed. 
Here is my route print status of 200 and 0.
[Root Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Rcu.jpg)

What static route should I add? if any, or what other work around are possible?

Comment: have you tried this yes? http://lmgtfy.com/?q=isa+server+routing

Comment: Yes and tried to add different routes but no idea where am making mistake, actually not a core network guy.

Comment: the ISA server is a proxy server for outbound internet access, it sits at the edge of your network - usually all vlans are configured to proxy out via ISA but the inter VLAN routing should happen inside the network and not at its' perimeter - so you need to configure your layer 3 switch.. what is the default for your clients? a VLAN gateway or the ISA?

Comment: I am able to ping other single NIC machines of vlan1 to vlan2 or vice versa. Hence switches are configured properly. My only concern is to send a ping between the vlans and not to proxy for internet. I have mentioned  ISA in my question to explain the server details only.

Comment: Any chances to get a solution here?